# How to check if database table is empty in java play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm able to retrieve data from database but not to add condition which will display an alert when database table is empty.

Here is my code:

#### `index.scala.html`:

```
@(formList: List[Users],form: Form[Users])

@main("history") {

    @for(i <- Users.all()) {

        @if(i.client.equalsIgnoreCase("potato")) {

            <Table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i >@i.firstname @i.lastname </i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i>@i.phonenumber</i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i>@i.amount</i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i>@i.doneAt</i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="@routes.Application.edit(i.id)"><i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil "></span></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="@routes.Application.delete(i.id) "><i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash "></span></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    }
}
```

#### Controller method:

```
public static Result history(long id) {
    Form<Users> taskData = form(Users.class);
    return ok(history.render(Users.all(), taskData));
}
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? Are you sure that this view/template is related to the action/controller method you posted? What exactly you want to check?

Comment: i am using play 2.2.6 , i what to check if database table is empty before fetch data from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr Move `User.all()` to the controller and pass it via template parameters, then add the if statement to render the alert if the list is empty.

---

You’ll have to add an if statement to check if the user list is empty, and display the alert if it is.

```
@if (Users.all().isEmpty) {
  // Show the alert.
}
```

In order to avoid fetching the users twice, you could use the `defining` function.

```
@defining(Users.all()) { users =>
  @if (users.isEmpty) {
    // Show the alert.
  }
  @for(user <- users) {
    …
  }
}
```

But I’d strongly suggest to move the user fetching to the controller, and make the template accept the user list as a parameter. That way you’ll keep the template simple. When it gets rendered, it will just present the data, instead of potentially doing heavy-lifting like fetching records from the database.

The end result could look like this.

### Template

```
@(users: List[Users], formList: List[Users],form: Form[Users])

@main("history") {

    @if (users.isEmpty) {
        <div class="alert">
            …
        </div>
    }

    @for(i <- users) {

        @if(i.client.equalsIgnoreCase("potato")) {

            <Table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i >@i.firstname @i.lastname </i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i>@i.phonenumber</i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i>@i.amount</i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="/#"><i>@i.doneAt</i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="@routes.Application.edit(i.id)"><i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil "></span></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="@routes.Application.delete(i.id) "><i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash "></span></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public static Result history(long id) {
    Form<Users> taskData = form(Users.class);
    return ok(history.render(Users.all(), Users.MTN(), taskData));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @jokka for your answer is helpful for me.

i simply add the following lines in my template **index.scala.html**

```
  @if(formList.isEmpty) {
              <div class="alert">
               <p>Sorry no sold airtime found today</p>
                  </div>
                   }
              @for(i <- Users.all()) {
             .........
```